# OTP generation is specific to SIM or Phone number

Tags: mobile, one-time-password

Are the messages including OTP sent to a mobile phone addressed to the SIM card or the phone number?

If I decide to have a new phone number and the old phone number is allotted to a new customer, the bank may send the OTP to the same old number even if I have the SIM.

So is OTP or messages sent to the SIM?
Are text messages specific to SIM or specific to phone number?

Answer (score 4):

SMS messages are always sent to a phone number. If you don't have access to the phone number registered for 2 factor authentication at some provider, let them know immediately so they can remove the number.

Answer (score 0):

They are specific to the phone number. Before you change your phone number (SIM) you should first disable 2FA and re-enable it with the new number.